# Maven-build using Groovy-Eclipse compiler plugin includes *.groovy files in jars

Tags: maven, groovy, eclipse-rcp, tycho, groovy-eclipse

I set up a Maven build for an Eclipse RAP project.
The project contains java and groovy.
The Maven build works without errors but resulting JARs contain both the compiled class files **and** the groovy source files for most of the classes.

**I only expected the compiled class-files.**

Not being a groovy programmer, I'm lost there.
The groovy source-files do not turn up in the jars when using the warexport tool in eclipse.

For the project setup I used the instructions from here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven

Groovy and java files are located in src/main/java in every plugin project.
We're not using groovy-scripts.

Thanks for any hints to solve the problem.

Comment: What is the problem? Please edit the question to make this more clear, e.g. by describing the expected result.

Comment: I only expected class-files but i always get both groovy and class-files together. This is for example a typical output: Answer_Lifecycle.class Answer_Lifecycle.groovy Exam_Lifecycle.class Exam_Lifecycle.groovy etc

Answer (score 0):

Which maven plugin are you using to compile groovy?
You can use

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>addSources</goal>
              <goal>addTestSources</goal>
              <goal>generateStubs</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
              <goal>removeStubs</goal>
              <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <!-- any version of Groovy \>= 1.8.2 should work here -->
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```